# Multibit showing account balance as zero

Tags: blockchain, unconfirmed-transactions, multibit

MultiBit showing my balance as zero.  Plus I have a transaction that has been unconfirmed for 18 days [blockchain link to unconfirmed transaction](https://blockchain.info/tx-index/60c125ad41aa8db424e3852716ae263089b096e475906a4e3e03eb8c18a0d6b4)

wtf... this is not cool... Need the money asap...  Bitcoin is not as cool as I thought...

Tried repairing wallets three times to no avail.

Is there anything I can do to get the money that is displayed in the image to be available to spend?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it needs to be confirmed by at least 6 blocks before MultiBit 'allows' you to spend them (and the status changes from 'unconfirmed' to your actual balance). Did you include enough miner's fee?

In the "payments" tab, you can see the status of the transaction as well as a small green pie chart (1/6th = 1 block), reflecting the amount of blocks that have confirmed it.

Answer (score 0):

Repairing the wallet will not do anything, because the problem here is that the incoming payment is not confirmed.

You could either wait it out, or try to create a CPFP transaction, but I don't think that MultiBit has support for that. Anyway, the transaction appears to have confirmed by now.